Make Spotlight ignore external disks?
I have Time Machine backing up to four external disks, rotating one each week to another location.  But I have another where I manually run a script to back up a website and two specific large directory trees.  This disk will not eject, and gives no explanation when I try.  I suspect it is because as soon as it gets a new backup, Spotlight starts indexing it and 500GB takes a while.
Unfortunately, in Sequoia 15.1.1 (24B91), external disks cannot be added to the Spotlight exclusion with the Settings GUI.  Clicking "+" does not allow navigating to them.  Drag-and-drop from Finder does nothing.
defaults read com.apple.IMCoreSpotlight contains a key of
IMCSDoNotIndex =     (
);

but after I add two directories to the exclusions (with the Settings GUI), that key remains empty.
If I read all nine domains associated with Spotlight, and search for those directories, neither is mentioned.
Is there another way to get an external disk excluded?

Tried lsof to look for the external disk but it hung.  Wouldn't give back the prompt on Crtrl-C and after exiting that Terminal, Finder was dead.  Attempt to restart cleared all the icons off the Desktop, but then the background image remained until I got tired of waiting and forced power off.
